# Mismatched contacts SubTypes - Contacts will not be imported when Suptype is not the first Subtype

Tags: error, import, csv, sub-types

**CiViCRM 5.65.1 on Drupal 9.5.10 PHP Version 7.4.30**
When I import users from a CSV file to a certain contact subtype (I want to import or update data of all Supervisors)
[image: Import]
only those entries from the CSV will be imported, where the **first** subtype is Supervisor.
[image: partial]

The 47 successfully imported users have the subtype Supervisor **either as the only or as the first type** on their contact page in CiViCRM:

[image: Supervisorfirst]

The others where Supervisor is **an additional or second contact subtype** will not be imported:
[image: Supervisornotfirst]

[image: ImportMismachtCSV]
Mismatched contact SubTypes

Please excuse that the screenshots are in German and thank you in advance.